# "Инвертируется" график функции. Как сделать его нормальным?

Tags: c#

Вот код. График функции "инвертируется".

```
for (int x = -8; x < 5; x++)
{
int y = (int)Math.Abs(Math.Pow(x, 2) + 4 * x);
Console.SetCursorPosition(x+8, y);
Console.Write("*");
}
```

[image: Как выглядит результат выполнения кода]
[image: Как должен выглядеть график]

Comment: что значит "инвертируется"?

Comment: @Grundy
Добавила 2 картинки. На первой результат программы, на второй как должно быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На верхней картинке (командная строка) 0 по оси Y находится вверху и плюс идёт сверху вниз. На нижней (обычный график) - внизу. Делайте выводы и исправляйте код в нужную сторону.

Comment: Спасибо. Кажется, всё получилось :)